# How to sign a letter in Esperanto?

Tags: word-choice

In English, at the end of a letter, e-mail message, etc., one writes something along the lines of:

- Sincerely,
- Best wishes,
- All the best,
- Best regards,

(with the comma) And then on the next line goes the name of the sender.

Example:

> Best regards,
>
> Lyubo

What should be used there when the letter is in Esperanto? It probably (like in English) depends on how well you know the intended reader. If that is so, please give examples for the various “levels” of knowing the person.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The formal expression:

> Kun afablaj salutoj

If you consider the person a friend:

> Kun amikaj salutoj

More informally:

> Amike salutas

Or even simpler:

> Amike

To really closed friends or beloved ones:

> Brakume
>
> Ame

Answer (score 1):

Between Esperantists, instead of *Amike*, the expression *Samideane* tends to be used.

Comment: That is not so much an independent answer as more of a comment to the previous one.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that signing off with “samideane” is not completely neutral and it may carry a slight political meaning. I know some esperantists object to being called “samideano”.

Comment: Often signing off can be political, and if you want to avoid calling someone a friend, Samideane can still be both well-received and honest.

Answer (score 0):

In English you also find "Cheers", whose translation "je via sano" only apply for toast when drinking. Maybe "Danke" povus taŭgi.

Answer (score 0):

This whole chapter deals with writing letters: http://pages.ucsd.edu/~dkjordan/eo/colloq/colloq150.html